# Avoid having to put setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false) everywhere

Tags: ios

I was wondering, now with Auto Layout you have to tell every `UIView` that you don't want to translate its (deprecated) auto-resizing masks to layout constraints like so:

```
let view = MyView()
view.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
```

In my app, I do (almost) all my views with custom constraints so I never want automatic translation of auto-resizing masks. Wouldn't it be nice if the default setting for this would be `false`? So only in situations where I DO want translation of auto resizing masks I set it to `true`?

Is there a way to make `false` the default for `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`? Maybe with a clever extension (a.k.a. category) of some sort?

Answer (score 3):

I fully agree which is why I made [this category](https://github.com/jrturton/UIView-Autolayout) which includes such an initialiser:

```
extension UIView {

    // MARK: Initializing a View Object

    /**
    * @name Initializing a View Object
    */

    /**
    *  Returns a frameless view that does not automatically use autoresizing (for use in autolayouts).
    *
    *  @return A frameless view that does not automatically use autoresizing (for use in autolayouts).
    */
    class func autoLayoutView() -> Self {
        let view = self()
        view.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        return view
    }
}
```

There is a swift branch in the project as well, but this is very early stage. Pull requests welcome!

Comment: Wonderful blog entries by @jrturton on auto layout, must read for any newbie: http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2013/01/31/visual-format-language-for-autolayout/

Comment: @gregzo thanks so much! Nice to know they're helping!

Answer (score 1):

Why not a category on UIView?

header:

```
@interface UIView( MaskKiller )

- ( instancetype )myInit;
```

implementation:

```
@implementation UIView( MaskKiller )

- ( instancetype )myInit
{
     if( self = [ self init ] )
     {
          self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
     }
     return self;
}
```

Edit: Went a bit quickly here, of course that solves nothing when dealing with UIView subclasses. In that case, swizzling might be an option.

Comment: Good overview of swizzling here, by the way: http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/